# How to speed up search for a line containing needed text?

Tags: python, regex, xml, lxml

I have the first file (about 1-3 kb in size) a few lines of which look like this::

```
Name1
Name2
Name3
Name4
etc
```

And there is a second file (1.2 GB in size) in which the string looks like this:

```
<root><img>url</img><title>Name1</title>(a few more tags there)</root>
```

The second file contains all the names of the first file (and also the names of the same files as file1), but with additional information.

I need a code to go through each line of file1, take the name from there and look for a tag containing the same name in file 2. After it finds the tag containing the desired name, it is necessary to copy the parent root tag and everything in it to output file.

I got this code:

```
root = ET.parse('file2.xml').getroot()

with open('output.xml', 'a') as x, open('file1.xml', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        element = line
        search = root.xpath('.//root/Title[text()="%s"]' % element)
        for i in search:
            print(ET.tostring(i.getparent().decode('utf-8')))
```

It' s working, but it's veery slow and I need to speed up this code

Question: How can I speed up this code or is there an alternative fast way to search for element by text?

## Edit

Structure of each line in a large file (pretty printed)

```
<root>
  <Big_Images>
    <Big_Images0>url to img</Big_Images0>
    <Big_Images1>url to img</Big_Images1>
  </Big_Images>
  <Small_Images>
    <Small_Images0>url to small img</Small_Images0> 
    <Small_Images1>url to small img</Small_Images1> 
  </Small_Images>
  <title>Name1</title>
  <Summary/> # can contain some info
  <Price>4.1</Price>
  <Main_Info>
    <item>many html code there</item>
  </Main_Info>
</root>
```

Small_Images(number from 0(`<Small_Images/>`) to 10) always equals Big_Images(number from 0(`<Big_Images/>`) to 10)

I have also deleted all duplicate strings (in a large file). Either there is no string containing, for example, Name1, or there is only 1 string containing Name1.

`root` always contains 1 `title` tag

Only `Summary` , `Big_Images` and `Small_Images` may not have an element

In the xml file there is 1 parent tag `data`, each line in which has a `root`

Comment: Idea1: `.//root/title` could be inefficient. Try `/root/title` instead (this assumes that `<root>` is indeed the root tag of your XML file. If not, adjust appropriately). Idea2: instead of reading a small file sequentially and doing a random search on a big file, read the small file into memory (e.g. into a set), then read the big file sequentially and look up the names in the set in memory.

Comment: In terms of XPath it seems a bit odd that you explicitly select `root/Title` and then go up with `i.getparent`, it seems directly using `search = root.xpath('.//root[title ="%s"]' % element)` and then simply `print(ET.tostring(i.decode('utf-8')))` should suffice. I haven't made any tests whether that improves performance. In general, with data that large (1.2 GB), it might make sense to use a database like BaseX as it allows you to build an index and then searches become much faster. BaseX is implemented in Java but has a Python client API http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Clients.

Comment: It would help if you provide more details on the exact file structure, in particular, will there be or can there be several `title` elements with the same value (e.g. several `<title>Name1</title>` elements)? Is the parent element of a `title` element always a `root` element? Is the nesting level of those `title` elements always the same or are the different levels?

Comment: I updated the data in the header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your advice, in my case I wrote this working code:

```
with open('main_data_file.xml', 'r') as f:
    txt = ''.join(f.readlines())
    with open('names.txt', 'r') as g, open('output.txt', 'a') as x:
        for element in g.readlines():
            line_regexp = r'^(.*<title>%s</title>.*)$' % element
            matches = re.search(line_regexp, txt, re.MULTILINE)
            try:
              x.write(matches + "\n")
            except AttributeError:
              pass
```

But he's still too slow(about 5 seconds for 1 KB)

I don't know where I'm wrong and can I search for a line with the right name faster?

## Edit

I've tested a lot and found the right code for me:

```
data_set = set()
with open('main_data_file.xml', 'r') as f:
    data_set.update(f.readlines())
    with open("names.txt", 'r', encoding='utf-8') as g, open("output.txt", 'a') as x:
        for line in g.readlines():
            line_regexp = '<title>%s</title>' % line.strip()
            # print('Searching line:' + line_regexp)
            for element in data_set:
                if line_regexp in element:
                    x.write(element)
                    # print('Element found ' + line.strip() + "\n")
```

Operating at high enough speed

Comment: As I understand it, the problem is re.search(), what do you think about it?

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try regex approach

```
import re

names = []
with open("small_file", "r") as f:
    names = f.readlines()

with open("big_file", "r") as f:
    pattern = re.compile(r"\<root\>[\W\w]*\<\/root\>")
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        match = pattern.search(line)
        if match:
            print(line)
```